# How to create a circular (Endless) Lazycolumn/LazyRow in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to achieve infinite like list in Lazycolumn/LazyRow.When scrolled to the end, I would like to views to be visible while the displaying data from the top of the list or when scrolled to the top of the list I would display data from the bottom of the list.

Comment: How about using data items as circular list?

Comment: sorry, @Varsha Kulkarni what you mean?

Comment: I haven't implemented, but thought [this](https://gist.github.com/ToxicBakery/05d3d98256aaae50bfbde04ae0c62dbd) would be useful.

Answer (score 8):

I think something like this can work:

```
@Composable
fun CircularList(
    items: List<String>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onItemClick: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState(Int.MAX_VALUE / 2)

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        items(Int.MAX_VALUE, itemContent = {
            val index = it % items.size
            Text(text = items[index])    // item composable
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! I changed `rememberLazyListState(Int.MAX_VALUE / 2)` to `rememberLazyListState(Int.MAX_VALUE / 2 - (Int.MAX_VALUE / 2) % items.size)` so that the list starts at the first item.

Comment: Can someone explain the significance of using Int.MAX_VALUE/2 when we are using Int.MAX_VALUE for list count?

Comment: @RahulRawat, Sure, with `Int.MAX_VALUE / 2` we're saying that initial position of our list is in the middle of `Int.MAX_VALUE`, so we have `Int.MAX_VALUE / 2` from the top (or start) and from the bottom (or end) of the list. Meaning the list is "endless" in both directions.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the explanation. I figured this out while playing around with this, since I wanted to start at the start of the list and have it extend endlessly, I ended us just using rememberLazyListState().

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, you can make it customizable to support both variants of the list.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CircularList(
    items: List<String>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    isEndless: Boolean = false,
    onItemClick: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState(
        if (isEndless) Int.MAX_VALUE / 2 else 0
    )

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        items(
            count = if (isEndless) Int.MAX_VALUE else items.size,
            itemContent = {
                val index = it % items.size
                Text(text = items[index])    // item composable
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: OP asked for a circular list, meaning scrolling from bottom to top too. This would only work scrolling from top to bottom

Comment: These aren't really circular lists. They're just really really really really long repeating lists. If your user scrolls for a very long time, they will get to the end on either side. Setting the initialScroll to half the range is what makes it as "circular" from the top as the bottom.