# Trying to make a infinite scrolling animated vertical carousel but can't get it to scroll infinite

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have created this composable that automatically scrolls through it's content. When it reaches the last item in the list it doesn't keep scrolling in the same direction but it scroll the opposite direction back to the first item.

I can't seem to get it to keep scroll downwards.

```
@Composable
fun AnimatedVerticalColumn(
    content: ArrayList<@Composable (Modifier) -> Unit>,
    animationTime: Int = 1500,
    delay: Long = 10000
) {
    var currentIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while (true) {
            delay(delay)

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % content.size
            }
        }
    }

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(52.dp)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(content) { index, item ->
            val density = LocalDensity.current

            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = index == currentIndex,
                enter = slideInVertically(
                    initialOffsetY = { if (index == 0 && currentIndex == content.size - 1) with(density) { -52.dp.roundToPx() } else with(density) { 52.dp.roundToPx() } },
                    animationSpec = tween(animationTime)
                ) + expandVertically(
                    expandFrom = Alignment.Bottom,
                    animationSpec = tween(animationTime)
                ),
                exit = slideOutVertically(
                    targetOffsetY = { if (index == content.size - 1 && currentIndex == 0) with(density) { 52.dp.roundToPx() } else with(density) { -52.dp.roundToPx() } },
                    animationSpec = tween(animationTime)
                ) + shrinkVertically(
                    shrinkTowards = Alignment.Top,
                    animationSpec = tween(animationTime)
                )
            ) {
                item(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(52.dp)
                        .padding(2.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can test this via this;

```
val list: ArrayList<@Composable (Modifier) -> Unit> = arrayListOf(
        { modifier ->
            Text(modifier = modifier, text = "item one")
        },
        { modifier ->
            Text(modifier = modifier, text = "item two")
        },
        { modifier ->
            Text(modifier = modifier, text = "item three")
        },
    )

    AnimatedVerticalColumn(list, delay = 3000)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for making this work as i want it to?

Comment: Suprisingly, it seems like there is no clean solution to this. All answers I found include a workaround setting the item count to Integer.MAX_VALUE and thus only simulating "endless" scrolling. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66503121/how-to-create-a-circular-endless-lazycolumn-lazyrow-in-compose

Comment: I don't think that that will be a good fix performance wise, do you?

Comment: `LazyColumn` is designed to lazily load the items, so its primary goal is to not slow down performance when many items are added. I think it should not be a problem for performance, but I agree with you that this feels like an overkill/dirty hack solution.